# java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent()'s purpose and behavior

Tags: java, swing, components, awt, dispatchevent

Most of the [tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html) and documentation that I've been reading seem to indicate that most component communication takes place by subscription using [listeners](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getListeners(java.lang.Class)).

The Java [docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#dispatchEvent(java.awt.AWTEvent)) indicate that `java.awt.Component#dispatchEvent(AWTEvent e)`:

> Dispatches an event to this component or one of its sub components. Calls processEvent before returning for 1.1-style events which have been enabled for the Component.

Given that listeners seem commonplace, what is the purpose of `dispatchEvent` and how / where is the dispatched event received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component has to receive the events to dispatch somewhere. This is where a component receives the events. The events come from the `EventQueue`.

Comment: So this would likely be used internally by Java as it notices an event coming in from the OS/Gui system, such as native mouse clicks, etc., and not for inter-component communication where you have full programmatic control over the events?

Comment: How do you mean? It's not for day-to-day code. And you can't override it.

Comment: In other words, I really don't need to use it because I can create my own events and event listeners.  The raw AWT code may use it to dispatch certain events, but I need not concern myself with it because I will be notified of the events through some listener where relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I researched how to send custom events to a JFrame, and finally I succeeded in compiling some examples found on the web.

The functional result is visible here:

[link text](http://serge.coude.net/code-source/java.php5#java-MyEventDemo.java)

Hoping that it might be useful!

Serge COUDÉ